# Is it possible to use a Func<T> generic as a property that can be dynamically populated with a method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, action, func

I am working on a card game of sorts and I've been trying to figure out how to handle unique card effects on the Card class. I've included the class below. I'm trying to add an "effect" property to the class that can be populated in the constructor or later via a setter if needed. The problem I have is I don't know if this method will have a return type or the same return type. The simple way would seem to be to say that effect methods in the game cannot return values and simply define the property as an Action but it's definitely nice to be able to return something in certain situations (mostly testing situations where you might want to confirm the proper Card or List<Card> is returned or even the proper player or deck object).

I'm extremely new to `c#` and am probably missing something or misunderstanding generics. I've added type object because that gets me out the door with the getter and setter but I don't know if object will inherently allow me to return a class the isn't actually extended from object.

```cs
using System;
[System.Serializable]

public class Card
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int Cost { get; set; }
  public int Power { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public Func<object> Effect { get; set; }
  
  public Card()
  {

  }

  public Card(int id, string title, int cost, int power, string description, Func<object> effect)
  {
    Id = id;
    Title = title;
    Cost = cost;
    Power = power;
    Description = description;
    Effect = effect;
  }
}
```

I initially tried just defining it as:

```cs
private Func<> effect;

public Func<> Effect
{
  get { return effect; }
  set { effect = value; }
}
```

I expected that without defining a type it would allow me to return a non-null type but I suspect I'm misunderstanding the usage of generics here.

Comment: One thing you *definitely* want to learn about is automatically-implemented properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties - all of your code other than the constructors could be done in just 6 lines. (I'd also recommend you follow conventions around parameter names, and remove those underscores.)

Comment: well, you can use generics, however you have to provide a type-argument when you use the `Card`-class, e.g. `new Card<MyType>(...)` making the entire class itself generic - not just the property, which is not possible.

Comment: `if object will inherently allow me to return a class the isn't actually extended from object.` .. that's impossible ;) `object` is the implicit mother class of **everything** in `c#`

Comment: Separately, it's basically not clear to me how the effect is going to be used. *Maybe* you want `Card` to be generic, but it's hard to know, because we don't know enough about the use case.

Comment: Thanks for the additional documentation @JonSkeet. I've updated the class to reflect that information. I was trying to follow the best standards I could find but a lot of youtube tutorial videos and such are dated.

The idea here is for the Card class to be a blueprint for all cards in the game. Not a generic, but more of something for future cards to potentially extend.

The effects property is meant to hold a method defined in the card constructor that might call a variety of other methods such as:
Deck.PutOnTop(Card)
Deck.Shuffle()
Deck.Draw(int)
Deck.Search(Card)

Comment: Those sound like odd things to store in a Card, to be honest. They sound like things that someone might want to do *with* a card rather than things the card itself should "know" about.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's a good call out for sure. I'm wondering if my structure is just wrong.

Right now I have an object structure like this:

A Player class which has it's own Deck instance and Hand instance. These are essentially List<Card> objects with additional methods. The idea was to find a way to encapsulate each Card knowing what effect it needed to execute when played from the players Hand. Perhaps I'm structuring it wrong the idea was to have the Card dispatch events that the deck and hand could listen for and resolve. I come from a web development background so probably thewrong way

Comment: Yeah, I really don't think you need an eventing approach here. I would expect whatever is coordinating the game to be responsible for moving cards from deck, to hand, to table or whatever.

Comment: @JonSkeet so it sounds like perhaps I need a GameManager class that is managing the state of the game. I had seen other people use this but was in the mindset of Objects talking to each other given my background, perhaps it's more efficient here to have that GameManager dictating to each class how to function. I may just need to look for some documentation on best practices for structuring/modeling applications in ``c#`` as well. Compiled languages are definitely a different boat than scripting languages.

Comment: I found this pretty quickly:
https://resources.unity.com/games/level-up-your-code-with-game-programming-patterns

I think I was looking at the game from the Observer pattern as that's what's most familiar but in this case something like the Command pattern might be more beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper use of a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) would be e.g.

```
private Func<T> effect;
public Func<T> Effect => effect;
```

This would require though that `Card` itself is generic as well (`Card<T>`) with the same type restrictions.

The only exception is having a **method** which allows you to pass in the generic type once you call it

```
public Func<T> GetEffect<T>()
{
    return ???;
}
```

This very much depends on your other code though and how exactly you are intending to consume this property. If you go for generics you will also need to explicitly provide a type when you consume it.

So I just claim now this is most probably not what you wanted to do anyway.

---

I think instead you might want to rather have something like e.g.

```
public interface ICardEffect
{
    public void RunEffect(/*whatever you need like e.g. GameManager etc*/);
}
```

and then rather

```
public ICardEffect Effect { get; private set; }
```

this you can pass in via the constructor and consume properly without needing to know/return the exact implementing type.

This will still make little sense in a `[Serializable]` class which you configure via the Inspector which will not use any special constructor but rather the default parameter-less one.

---

#### Alternative Approach

I think in your Unity specific case you would be better of using [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) assets. A `ScriptableObject` is mainly intended to be a "data container" but in the end it is a c# class so it can also implement own behavior. Something I use to call "scriptable behavior".

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Card : ScriptableObject
{
    //[field: SerializeField] public int Id { get; private set;} // don't really need this as the asset reference is unique already 
    //[field: SerializeField] public string Title { get; private set;} // don't really need this as the asset itself already has a name 
    [field: SerializeField] public int Cost { get; private set;}
    [field: SerializeField] public int Power { get; private set;}
    [field: SerializeField] public string Description { get; private set;}

    [field: SerializeField] public CardEffect Effect { get; private set;}
}
```

You create instances of this via the Assets -> right click -> Create -> Card

And then populate it via the Inspector. Later you can use this just as you would e.g. Textures and other assets and drag it into your game managers list for instance.

And then for the `CardEffect` you do the same and have e.g.

```
public abstract class CardEffect : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void RunEffect(/*whatever you need like e.g. GameManager etc*/);
}
```

and then create specific effects like e.g. (I don't know your use case and types of course)

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class DrawEffect : CardEffect
{
    [SerializeField][Min(1)] int amount = 1;

    public override void RunEffect(GameManager game)
    {
        game.DrawCard(amount);
    }
}
```

you can create as many subtypes of effects as you wish and reference them in your `Card` instances. You can even make the `Card.Effect` rather a list and chain combine multiple effects together.

Comment: I think perhaps this ScriptableObject approach makes more sense but I had read about issues with ScriptableObject in multiplayer. I believe the stuff I read stated that scriptable object is shared between players and added some additional complication.

Comment: Well `ScriptableObject` is an asset .. like material or texture .. so if you reference that in multiple places yes, you are using the same instance. But as you can see above the card asset itself only has some values and the effect does stuff .. it wouldn't matter at all if two things reference the same .. this has little to do with multiplayer at all tbh

Comment: That totally makes sense, thanks for clarifying. I think I'll take a shot at it this way and this is actually more scalable to some of the other systems we wanted to implement as far as cards being upgraded with additional effects (ala Monster Train).

Comment: when I use the example above it says that [MinValue(1)] is missing a namespace. I dug around and it appears that int32 Min Value should be in System.Runtime.dll but including "using System" or "using System.Runtime" didn't resolve it.

Comment: try [`[Min]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MinAttribute.html) instead ... is a Unity attribute and I always confuse them (I think Odin provides `MinValue` and `MaxValue`)^^

Comment: That worked the final code I ended up with for that class after experimenting is:

```using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class DrawEffect : CardEffect
{
  [SerializeField][Min(1)] int amount = 1;

  public DrawEffect() { }

  public DrawEffect(int amount)
  {
    this.amount = amount;
  }
</code></pre>
  public override void RunEffect(Player player, Player opponent)
  {
    player.Deck.Draw(this.amount);
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is I don't know if this method will have a return type or the same return type

You have to have specify some return type, possibly object, or a generic type. Using a generic type does not make much sense, since you cannot use it, since it is of some unknown type (unless you use a generic restriction). If you return an object you can at least check the type. But chances are you should use an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) instead of an action/func property.

> I don't know if object will inherently allow me to return a class the isn't actually extended from object

All types in c# derive from object. Note that value types will be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) when used in this way.